# Flutter - How to register abstract classes in get_it (service locator)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stream

I'm currently working on a simple project crypto_wallet. **State management (BLoC)** and **Value Equality (freezed)** creating **CRUD** operation of DB (Firebase) and in the watch method, I use **StreamSubcription** code is :

```
@injectable
class CoinWatcherBloc extends Bloc<CoinWatcherEvent, CoinWatcherState> {
  final ICoinRepository _repository;

  CoinWatcherBloc(this._repository, this._coinStreamSubscription) : 
 super(CoinWatcherState.initial());

  StreamSubscription<Either<CoinFailure, KtList<CoinEntity>>>? _coinStreamSubscription;

  @override
  Stream<CoinWatcherState> mapEventToState(CoinWatcherEvent event) async* {
    yield* event.map(
      watchCoin: (e) async* {
        yield CoinWatcherState.loadInProgress();
        await _coinStreamSubscription?.cancel();
        _coinStreamSubscription = _repository.watchCoin().listen(
              (failureOrSuccess) => add(
                CoinWatcherEvent.coinsReceived(failureOrSuccess),
              ),
            );
      },
      coinsReceived: (e) async* {
        yield e.failureOrCoin.fold(
          (f) => CoinWatcherState.loadFailure(f),
          (coin) => CoinWatcherState.loadSuccess(coin),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    await _coinStreamSubscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

And at last I closed the stream. I inject all third party modules on **@lazySingleton** :

```
@module
abstract class FirebaseInjectableModule {
  @lazySingleton
  FirebaseAuth get firebaseAuth => FirebaseAuth.instance;
  @lazySingleton
  FirebaseFirestore get firebaseFirestore => FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @lazySingleton
  GoogleSignIn get googleSignIn => GoogleSignIn();
}
```

Then It says :

```
Object/factory with  type StreamSubscription<Either<CoinFailure, KtList<CoinEntity>>> is not 
registered inside GetIt. 
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
```

If I also register this class like this.

```
@lazySingleton
StreamSubcription get streamSubcription => StreamSubcription();
```

Then it throws compile time error **that abstract classes can't be instantiated** like the all **Third Party Classes** I've registered. *How to inject abstract classes? Is there any other way to do this? or I shouldn't use StreamSubcription something else*? I'd be thankful <3 :)

Comment: did you find any solution for this ? I am also facing the same issue currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add `this._coinStreamSubscription` to your bloc's constructor. Remove it from the constructor, and declare it as a `late final` instance.

```
class CoinWatcherBloc extends Bloc<CoinWatcherEvent, CoinWatcherState> {
  final ICoinRepository _repository;

  CoinWatcherBloc(this._repository) : 
 super(CoinWatcherState.initial());

 late final StreamSubscription<Either<CoinFailure, KtList<CoinEntity>>>? _coinStreamSubscription;
```

`get_it` was trying to inject the abstract `streamSubscription` since it is in your constructor. And you do not need this. Also, if you look at it from a testing perspective, there is no need to mock the `streamSubscription`, you can instead mock the class that supplies data to it - which is the `repository` in this case

Answer (score -1):

I generally just inject the implementation of the abstract class like
`@LazySingleton(as:AbstractClass)`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: as:AbstractClass must be part of an older version or something.